# Copy files through RDP in a Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: copy, connect, rdp

I want to copy files through a Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2019 and my Computer. You can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt4h8.png) Open Remote desktop and click the local resource tab.

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeyKj.png) Check the clipboard box and click More

[image]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg2gO.png) Check drives and click ok.

[image]

Now, you should be able to copy files.